# selenium doesn't run when web page is loading

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am running some tests where I have to restart a server by clicking a "restart" button. There is a small text being displayed near to it which will show the status of the server.

Before clicking the "restart" button, the text shows "running" and after clicking it, the whole web page keeps loading and the text shows "restarting". After the page stops loading, the server successfully starts running again and the text shows "running".

I have to write a test case which checks if the text shows "restarting" when the "restart" button is clicked. But unfortunately I am not able to find a way to make the selenium check if the text is showing "restarting" as it is unable to do anything since the webpage is loading at that time.

Can anyone help me out by showing me a way how to make selenium run when the webpage is loading? I am not getting good replies in google search about this. It will be great if someone can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your code? where you able to click on the restart button?

Comment: Can you post the source of the page on which you are clicking on restart?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can drive a browser even the webpage is still loading. 
I would suggest to find the element for "restarting" and keeps checking it until 60 secs

In ruby, you do something like

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => X)
wait.until {driver.find_element(:id => 'restart_word')}

where X is the number of seconds to wait.

After X seconds, it will timeout.